# How to set failed in POSTMAN Collection runner via script

Tags: if-statement, console, postman, postman-collection-runner

How can I set a "FAILED" via script? I have a IF and in this if I want to check is X compare to Y. If not I want to get an "FAILED". For now I get an "FAILED" in my console but the test is "PASS". I already searched other sites but found nothing about this. Hope u now what I mean.

```
   if(pm.iterationData.get("ProfileSeries") == response.ProfileSeries){
    console.log("expProfileSeries " + pm.iterationData.get("ProfileSeries") + " = "+ response.ProfileSeries);
    }
    else{
         console.log("FAILED");
}
```

Comment: What is `response.ProfileSeries`? Can you provide an example of the response body please.

Answer (score 0):

Add `pm.test` with relevant `pm.expect`:

```
pm.test('ProfileSeries should be equal', function () {

pm.expect(pm.iterationData.get("ProfileSeries")).to.equal(response.ProfileSeries);

});
```